# WCF Rest service authentication in web config file

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am developing a WCFRest service and want to authenticate it by a single userid and password .
Go through the lot of stuff on internet .But the thing is complex.
I want to know is there any way to give the permission for single userid,password in web Config file .

```
 <Location path="Test.svc"> 
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <denyusers="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </Location
```

If there is any way to authenticate it   .Please Help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing: you do not want to just allow a specific USER, you want to allow a specific ROLE, i.e.  someone who is allowed to do that. Using a userID and Password means that if you ever need to change who is allowed (because that person has been fired, or because  there are now 2 people with that permission), you would have to change the web.config and redeploy the file, which in extreme cases might break the site.

Instead, implement an entire membership system, including roles, and then do this:

```
 <Location path="Test.svc"> 
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
          <allow roles="[RoleNameHere]">
          <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </Location>
```

You can then add the user that you want to give access to that role through the standard way of doing this for your membership provider, and s/he'll automatically be allowed access, while everyone else is denied. You can also easily change whoever is allowed or denied, because it's a data change, not a code change.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution .I am not using any membership provider ,I want to authenticate with only username="testusername" password="testpassword" nothing fancy  .Which i want to try in WCF restful service.

Comment: If you want to really use username, then replace `roles="..."` by `users="username"`. Beware of what I said though: it's not easily extensible, and if you make a mistake in the username, it'll break.

Comment: I am using this code in config file  <location path="TestService.svc">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="username"/>
        <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location> service method is always accessable .It does not ask for any authentication.